# Get BrowserSync external URL programmatically in Gulp file so I can pass it to an external node script?

Tags: node.js, gulp, browser-sync

I want to be able to send the browserSync external URL as a parameter for an external node script in my gulp file. How can I get at that external URL through the browserSync object (or some other way)?

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var shell = require('gulp-shell');
var browserSync = require('browser-sync').create();

gulp.task('default', ['browser-sync', 'config']);

gulp.task('browser-sync', function() {
    browserSync.init({
        proxy: "localhost:8024",
        open: "external"
    });
});

gulp.task('config', shell.task([
    "node scripts/someNodeScript.js browserSync.externalURL"
]));
```

---

UPDATE

Based on the excellent answer by @sven-shoenung below, I slightly tweaked his solution and am successfully using this:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var browserSync = require('browser-sync').create();
var spawn = require('child_process').spawn;

var externalUrl;

var browserSyncDone = function () {
    spawn('node', ['scripts/someNodeScript.js', externalUrl], {stdio:'inherit'});
};

gulp.task('default', ['browser-sync']);

gulp.task('browser-sync', function() {
    browserSync.init({
        proxy: "localhost:8024",
        open: "external"
    }, function() {
        externalUrl = browserSync.getOption('urls').get('external');
        browserSyncDone();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `browserSync.getOptions('urls')` to get a [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) of all access URLs. It returns something like this:

```
Map { 
  "local": "http://localhost:3000", 
  "external": "http://192.168.0.125:3000", 
  "ui": "http://localhost:3001",  
  "ui-external": "http://192.168.0.125:3001" 
}
```

Note that is only available **after** `browser-sync` is successfully initialized, so you need to pass a callback function to `browserSync.init()` or you'll try to get the value too soon.

You won't be able to use `gulp-shell` for the same reason. `shell.task()` will be set up **before** `browser-sync` has initialized, so `browserSync.getOptions('urls')` isn't available yet.

I recommend you use the standard nodejs [`child_process.spawn()`](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_spawn_command_args_options) instead.

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var browserSync = require('browser-sync').create();
var spawn = require('child_process').spawn;

var externalUrl;

gulp.task('default', ['browser-sync', 'config']);

gulp.task('browser-sync', function(done) {
  browserSync.init({
    proxy: "localhost:8024",
    open: "external"
  }, function() {
    externalUrl = browserSync.getOption('urls').get('external');
    done();
  });
});

gulp.task('config', ['browser-sync'], function(done) {
  spawn('node', ['scripts/someNodeScript.js', externalUrl], {stdio:'inherit'}).on('close', done);
});
```

Comment: Awesome, thank you so much for explaining this so well.

Comment: I had to slightly change things because gulp complained that the done() function didn't exist. What I'm successfully using I have posted in the original question. I'm not sure if it is bad form to post it there, but I wasn't sure.